# Gyro isn't working on Android device for Unity3D project

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm doing this tutorial https://youtu.be/T6bd_MQ2ass it is for iPhone tho.
I have followed the tutorial step by step and I can't figure out what seems to be the problem here.

Gyro of the phone is fine I tested for it (Moto G5) I don't have a webcam on my PC so can't say how it looks in the camera maybe that's why the image is so stretched out. I'm not too concerned about that just yet. if you could help me with that too it would be great.

This is the code for the main camera

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class webCamScript : MonoBehaviour {



public GameObject webCameraPlane; 
  public Button fireButton;


  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {

if (Application.isMobilePlatform) {
  GameObject cameraParent = new GameObject ("camParent");
  cameraParent.transform.position = this.transform.position;
  this.transform.parent = cameraParent.transform;
  cameraParent.transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, 90);
}

Input.gyro.enabled = false;
Input.gyro.enabled = true;

fireButton.onClick.AddListener (OnButtonDown);


WebCamTexture webCameraTexture = new WebCamTexture();
webCameraPlane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = webCameraTexture;
webCameraTexture.Play();




}


  void OnButtonDown(){

GameObject bullet = Instantiate(Resources.Load("bullet", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
Rigidbody rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
bullet.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
bullet.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position;
rb.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 1000f);
Destroy (bullet, 3);

GetComponent<AudioSource> ().Play ();




 }



  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {

Quaternion cameraRotation = new Quaternion (-Input.gyro.attitude.x, -Input.gyro.attitude.y, -Input.gyro.attitude.z, -Input.gyro.attitude.w);
this.transform.localRotation = cameraRotation;


  }
}
```

I'm doing this tutorial https://youtu.be/T6bd_MQ2ass it is for iPhone tho.
I have followed the tutorial step by step and I can't figure out what seems to be the problem here.

[This is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq3No.jpg)

[This is how it is looking (there is no gyro control here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT7of.jpg)